how to delete 400000 empty files by using google drive api
Somehow I got empty 400000 files which contains "scripts100.." . all Those files are in root drive and I need to get rid fo those using python script via google API. Google support is telling me select all files then delete but this is impossible and no meaningful support from google other than unfortunately.
I am not programmer but I searched and only option seems to me to get a Python script
I managed to connect to my Google Drive via Google Drive API to delete files via  this script below I used Chat GPT but it is slow always reaching maximum time thing
from Google import Create_Service

CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = "client_secret.json"
API_NAME = "drive"
API_VERSION = "v3"
SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]


service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)

def list_files():
    try:
        results = service.files().list(fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
        files = results.get('files', [])

        return files
    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred:", e)
        return []

def delete_file(file_id):
    try:
        service.files().delete(fileId=file_id).execute()
        print(f"File with ID {file_id} deleted successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while deleting file with ID {file_id}:", e)

# Get a list of all files
files = list_files()

# Delete each file
for file in files:
    delete_file(file['id'])


Is there any other way or a better option to fix this problem?

what exactly is the issue and what is max time thing. i would be careful with that it looks like its going to just delete everything

Does this answer your question? Deleting a huge number of files at root

If your script for deleting Google Drive files is reaching maximum execution time due to processing each file individually, you can optimize your approach by using batch requests. This method allows you to send multiple delete commands in a single HTTP request, reducing the time needed to process large numbers of files.
install this requirements by following:
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client google-auth google-auth-oauthlib google-auth-httplib2

Here's a script that implements batch requests:
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.http import BatchHttpRequest

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

def callback(request_id, response, exception):
    if exception:
        print(f"An error occurred: {exception}")
    else:
        print(f"Deleted file ID: {request_id}")

def main():
    flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('path_to_credentials.json', SCOPES)
    creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    results = service.files().list(pageSize=100, fields="nextPageToken, files(id)").execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])

    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
    else:
        batch = service.new_batch_http_request(callback=callback)
        for item in items:
            batch.add(service.files().delete(fileId=item['id']))
        batch.execute()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

